# Java: elegant for-loop with extra stop condition

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, int

We'd like a loop to either reach a certain index or run endlessly.
So we have a property **loopCount** that can be greater than 0 **OR** -1.

We'd like to have a loop that has 2 stopping conditions:
1. Arriving at **loopCount**.
2. Endlessly - **loopCount** == -1.

So here's the code:

```
for (int i = 0; (loopCount == -1 || i < loopCount) ; i++) {
   doSomething();
}
```

What's not elegant about this is that in case 
**loopCount** == -1 
i continues growing and might reach the INT_MAX.

Any ideas for a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4):

Why not exploit the fact that `||` *short-circuits*?

Use

```
for (int i = 0; loopCount == -1 || i++ < loopCount; /*intentionally blank*/) {
```

This way, `i` is only incremented *if* `loopCount` is *not* -1, and I've been careful enough to use `i++` rather than `++i`.

I've also dropped the unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: You asked "Why not exploit the fact that || short-circuits?". My answer would be: To keep the code more legible and to avoid side effects ... like incrementing variables in a condition check.

Comment: Coming from the C and C++ world, this kind of thing is idiomatic. This ain't VBA you know. But I respect the  downvote.

Comment: No, it's not VBA. It's Java.

Answer (score 4):

Consider separating this into two loops:

```
while(loopCount == -1){
    doSomething();
}
for (int i = 0; i < loopCount ; i++) {
    doSomething();
}
```

If loopCount = -1 then you'll have an endless while loop and the for loop will never be executed. If loopCount > 0 the while loop will be ignored and only the for loop will be executed.

Comment: Plus one; superior maintainability at the expense of elegance. And thinking about this some more, this is hardly inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is elegant enough ... but to keep it simple readable and all in one line

```
for (int i = 0; (loopCount == -1 || i < loopCount) ;  i = (loopCount > 0) ? i++ : i) {
    doSomething();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while(i == -1 || i < loopCount) {
    doSomething();
    if(i != -1)
        i++;
}
```

Runs endlessly while i == -1 buts only adds up in case its not an endlessly loop, avoiding i reach INT_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

For more readability and avoid short-circuit evaluation you can consider this solution

```
final int loopCount = 3; // -1
final boolean endlessly = (loopCount == -1);

int i = 0;
while (endlessly ? true : i++ < loopCount) {
    doSomething(i);
}
```

If `loopCount`is -1, the `while (true)` is executed endlessly. Otherwise `while (i++ < loopCount)` and the loop stops after count loops. The only drawback here is, that `i`counts from `1` up to `3`. In the endlessly case `i` is left untouched.